# PHP downloader for pdf header?

Tags: php, pdf

I've got a php file downloader that I've been using to download a word document, now I need to allow it to download pdfs and it won't open the document stating that the pdf is corrupted.

I've looked up the content-type, ect and t appears to be correct for pdfs, however, I'm unsure of what else it could be. Am I missing some more headers that are necessary for downloading pdfs? I'm very new to this so I'm uncertain of all the possible problems.

my code:

```
if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
$fsize = filesize($fullPath);
$path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
switch ($ext) {
    case "pdf":
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); 
    break;
    case "docx":
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    break;
    default;
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the PDF you're downloading in a text editor?

Comment: If your local pdf interpreter software fails to open a document you downloaded, then most likely that document is really broken. That has nothing to do with http headers, since it is a file on your local file system after the download. So the question is: what does that file contain? Did you check its size? How do the first bytes in there read?

Comment: I tried opening it into a text editor and its just a bunch of special characters. The file itself isn't corrupted, I can open it and it works perfectly from my directory. It just doesn't work when I download it. The file is an order form and its size is 281 KB

Comment: @user5166162 - so you've got a copy on the server, and a copy that's downloaded (that doesn't work). I'd suggest comparing the two files - grab something like WinDiff that will do a bit by bit comparison of the files, so you can at least see if it's being corrupted by the download

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
        header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Type: application/x-download");
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf"');
        header('Content-length: ' . filesize('test.pdf'));
        readfile('test.pdf');
```

This works for me every time. You can try it.

Comment: I tried this, but it still says it's damaged for some reason. I can open the file itself, I just can't open it when I download it. My word document I exported it from works fine when I download it through the code I have in my question. Could the export have done something to it?